# Does the equation $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y) + f(x)f(y) \pmod 2$ characterize $f(x) = (q \mid x), q$ a prime number where $(q\mid x) = 1$ if $q \mid x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $f : \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}_2$ be any map such that $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y) + f(x)f(y)$ and **$f$ is non-constant.**

Then can we always write $f(x) = (q \mid x)$ for some prime number $q$ **(or $1$)**?

The converse is easy since if $f(xy) = (q \mid xy) = 1$, then either $q \mid x$ *xor* $q \mid y$ *xor* $(q \mid x)(q\mid y)$ is equal to "$(q\mid x)$ or $(q \mid y)$".  In other words $q$ divides one but not both or it divides both.

Addition or $+$ modulo $2$ acts the same way as logical *xor* when treating $0$ as false and $1$ as true.  Similarly, multiplication modulo $2$ acts the same way as logical *and*.

Comment: Added in that $q = 1$ is always a possibility.

Comment: It's worth noting that the condition on $f$ is equivalent to $f(x)+1$ being completely multiplicative. This means $f$ is fully determined by its values at the primes.

Comment: @Servaes does that mean you did or you didn't find a counterexample?

Comment: @Servaes that is interesting to note, and I might use that later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A particular counterexample would be
$$f(x):=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }2\mid x\text{ or }3\mid x\\
0&\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}.$$
Of course this generalizes to arbitrary primes, and arbitrarily many of them.

Every such function $f$ is of this form, because the function $g(x):=f(x)+1$ satisfies
$$g(xy)=g(x)g(y),$$
i.e. it is completely multiplicative. This means $g(x)$ is fully determined by where it sends the primes, and hence so is $f(x)$. Choosing either $f(p)=1$ or $f(p)=0$ corresponds to including the condition $p\mid x$ or not.

Comment: Thank you!  You went above and beyond and actually characterized everything!

Answer (score 1):

The map $f(x)=1$ satisfies your equation, but there certainly is no prime that divides every $x$!  So no.

Comment: I added that $f$ can't be constant, to make this a more interesting question / answer.

Comment: Also your answer would have sufficed as a comment, so that I could reasonably change my question accordingly.